# TensorFlow create a dataset using generator for multiple columns with different data types

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I know that I can use `tensorflow.data.TextLineDataset` for this but I'd like to write a customized function to create a `DataSet` from a generator.

I'm implementing the input function for the census income data like this

```
_CSV_COLUMNS = [
    ('age', tf.int32),
    ('workclass', tf.string),
    ('fnlwgt', tf.int32),
    ('education', tf.string),
    ('education_num', tf.int32),

    ('marital_status', tf.string),
    ('occupation', tf.string),
    ('relationship', tf.string),
    ('race', tf.string),
    ('gender', tf.string),

    ('capital_gain', tf.int32),
    ('capital_loss', tf.int32),
    ('hours_per_week', tf.int32),
    ('native_country', tf.string),
    ('income_bracket', tf.string),
]

def input_csv(data_file, num_epochs, batch_size):
    df = pd.read_csv(data_file, header=None)

    def gen():
        for row in df.iterrows():
            row = row[1]
            yield dict(zip([n[0] for n in _CSV_COLUMNS[:14]], row[:14])), row[14] == '>50K'

    return tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen, (dict(_CSV_COLUMNS[:14]), tf.bool))
```

When I try this function with the `Estimator` API, it results in this error:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): assertion failed: [Feature (key: age) cannot have rank 0. Given: Tensor(\"IteratorGetNext:0\", dtype=int32)] [Condition x > 0 did not hold element-wise:] [x (linear/linear_model_1/linear_model/age/Rank:0) = ] [0]

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

---

Additional info:

I'm testing it with SageMaker local mode. The `train_input_fn` and `model_fn` are like

```
_NUMERIC_COLUMNS = [
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column(c) for c in
    ['age', 'education_num', 'capital_gain', 'capital_loss', 'hours_per_week']
]

def model_fn(features, labels, mode, hyperparameters):
    classifier = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(_NUMERIC_COLUMNS)
    return classifier.model_fn(features, labels, mode, None)

def train_input_fn(training_dir, hyperparameters):
    return input_csv(os.path.join(training_dir, 'adult.data.csv'), 3, 20)
```

The traceback is like (I added 2 blank lines around my source.)

```
Caused by op 'linear/linear_model_1/linear_model/age/assert_positive/assert_less/Assert/Assert', defined at:
  File "/usr/local/bin/entry.py", line 28, in <module>
    modes[mode]()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/container_support/training.py", line 36, in start
    fw.train()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tf_container/train_entry_point.py", line 164, in train
    train_wrapper.train()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tf_container/trainer.py", line 73, in train
    tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator=estimator, train_spec=train_spec, eval_spec=eval_spec)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 451, in train_and_evaluate
    return executor.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 617, in run
    getattr(self, task_to_run)()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 654, in run_master
    self._start_distributed_training(saving_listeners=saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 767, in _start_distributed_training
    saving_listeners=saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 376, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1145, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1170, in _train_model_default
    features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN, self.config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1133, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tf_container/trainer.py", line 108, in _model_fn
    return self.customer_script.model_fn(features, labels, mode, params)

  File "/opt/ml/code/train.py", line 32, in model_fn
    return classifier.model_fn(features, labels, mode, None)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 263, in public_model_fn
    return self._call_model_fn(features, labels, mode, config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1133, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/canned/linear.py", line 339, in _model_fn
    sparse_combiner=sparse_combiner)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/canned/linear.py", line 163, in _linear_model_fn
    logits = logit_fn(features=features)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/canned/linear.py", line 101, in linear_logit_fn
    cols_to_vars=cols_to_vars)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column.py", line 464, in linear_model
    retval = linear_model_layer(features)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 736, in __call__
    outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column.py", line 647, in call
    weighted_sum = layer(builder)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 362, in __call__
    outputs = super(Layer, self).__call__(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 736, in __call__
    outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column.py", line 539, in call
    weight_var=self._weight_var)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column.py", line 2030, in _create_weighted_sum
    weight_var=weight_var)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column.py", line 2043, in _create_dense_column_weighted_sum
    trainable=trainable)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column.py", line 2474, in _get_dense_tensor
    return inputs.get(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column.py", line 2263, in get
    transformed = column._transform_feature(self)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column.py", line 2442, in _transform_feature
    input_tensor = inputs.get(self.key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column.py", line 2250, in get
    feature_tensor = self._get_raw_feature_as_tensor(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column.py", line 2312, in _get_raw_feature_as_tensor
    key, feature_tensor))]):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/check_ops.py", line 198, in assert_positive
    return assert_less(zero, x, data=data, summarize=summarize)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/check_ops.py", line 559, in assert_less
    return control_flow_ops.Assert(condition, data, summarize=summarize)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/tf_should_use.py", line 118, in wrapped
    return _add_should_use_warning(fn(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 149, in Assert
    return gen_logging_ops._assert(condition, data, summarize, name="Assert")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_logging_ops.py", line 51, in _assert
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 454, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3155, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1717, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a Tensor object with different data types. Check out the [official doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tensors#data_types)

You can consider encoding everything as a string as the documentation suggests, or one hot encoding and further preprocessing before converting to a tensor, depending on your application.